# Set Minimum Password Length Firebase Email & Password Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

When using Firebase's Email & Password setting it seems like there are no security constraints on the password.

For example I could create the following user:

```
firebaseRef.createUser(
{
    email: "john.doe@example.org",
    password: "j"
});
```

I'd like to at least set a minimum password length. Does firebase provide a way to do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Update (2024): for Firebase projects that have upgraded to Identity Platform, you can now set the minimal password length (and other requirements). Check out the documentation on [password policies](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/password-policy).

Old answer below, just kept for reference.

---

**The below answer is outdated, check above for the latest**

There is currently no way to configure a minimum password length or strength for Firebase email+password Authentication.

You could build such a restriction into your app, but tech-savvy users can bypass that by calling the API. Or you could introduce a "isPasswordApproved" flag that only a server-side process can set, and then validate the password strength there. But neither of these sound very appealing.

Answer (score 32):

A `FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException` is thrown when using a weak password (less than 6 chars) to create a new account or to update an existing account's password. Use `getReason()` to get a message with the reason the validation failed that you can display to your users.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException for more details.

Comment: `String reason = ((FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException) task.getException()).getReason();`

Comment: In fact, just use `task.getException().getMessage()` also works as expected.

Answer (score 15):

I would argue that implementing front-end validation here should be enough (at least in a big portion of applications).

If the purpose of this validation is to protect the user himself, then there is no harm in allowing a user to hack your app and set the password to `password`, go to a forum and post the credentials, and jump out of a window.

Comment: The thing is the user can do a password reset and set a new password with no validation done by the app there (unless a custom auth handler is used).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the Reset Password form that Firebase sends.  It would be nice to use it and not have to build this out as well.

Comment: You can customize the reset password form and navigate the user to a custom URL. From there you can handle custom logic/backend calls etc.: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler