# Enforce custom rules for passwords for Firebase Auth accounts

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Is there any way that I could set custom rules for passwords when a user create an account? It seems like firebase doesn't provide a way to edit the password rules. I know I can set password rules on front end, but just like [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36319652/6516012) mentioned, this method can be bypassed by directly calling the API. Is is possible to write some cloud function to handle account-creation request, and reject the request if the password is invalid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can write a Cloud Function to create email/password accounts.  You'll need to use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to get a hold of [user management APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).

Comment: But what about reset password this uses the firebase UI

Comment: @Sigex unfortunately you need to override the Firebase UI by implementing your own UI that enforces the same password requirements.