# Force users to meet password requirements when using sendPasswordResetEmail() function

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm wondering if there is a way to force users to meet password requirements when using the sendPasswordResetEmail() function in flutter? 
When the user signs up and chooses a password I have certain requirements that the password must fulfill but when using sendPasswordResetEmail() these will not be considered since the new password is chosen in another UI by firebase and not in my app. Is there any way to set requirements even there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, enforcing a 'password-policy' cannot be done in `sendPasswordResetEmail()` function itself.

The authentication/verification can be done in both ways, back-end or it could be done in the front-end. Such as, validating the password in the initial stages before making the change.

But do **look out** for this [work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36319652) for your implemented password policies in the future!

I recommend implementing a hybrid, checking on the user-side followed by retrieving a flag from the server-side, this is to prevent the 'work-around' mentioned above!