# Block client-side password reset in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to do password resets exclusively through firebase functions so I can impose stricter rules (as [there is no way to change the rules through firebase auth API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36319652/12303271)) and run other logic

I can [update user passwords ok through functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user), but clients can always call the firebase api to [send a password reset email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email) or [update their password directly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_password). Is there a way to disable these, like how you can [disable client-side account creation & deletion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users?hl=en&authuser=0#user-actions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way in the Firebase Authentication of Cloud Identity APIs/console to disable client-side password reset, while leaving the other email/password functionality enabled. It's a reasonable feature request, so I'd recommend [filing it with the support team](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) or on [firebase.uservoice.com](https://firebase.uservoice.com).

For now, the only option to have email/password sign-in but not have client-side password reset functionality would be to [implement your own provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).